# Conversational Bot with Flan-T5

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, gpt-3, conversational-ai

I am building a chat bot using flan-T5 model. The bot has a text window where one can give instructions like:

- Summarize this for me "big text goes here"

Or, one might dump the text first in the chat window and then say

- Summarize the above text (or something similar to that)

Or, one might dump a bunch of domain specific facts in the chat window and then ask questions about those.

**Question:**

1. How can I form the context data for the bot so it has the knowledge about whatever info was passed to be before if it were to summarize something from before or answer quetsions from text that was passed before
2. How can I create a prompt which detects whether the intent is to `ASK QUESTION` or `CREATE SUMMARY` or just `INFO ADDITION` (in case we are just feeding info to use for asking questions or creating sumarry later.